# Calculate binomial coefficient for large n in Scala

Tags: scala

I was wondering in Scala, if there's any way of calculating the binomial coefficient, choose k from n, or the number of k-combinations from a set of n elements.

 It seems that for `n=1000` and `k=35`, we could face overflowing issue when calculating `35!` in Scala even when using Long.

 Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `BigInt` and `BigDecimal` when working with numbers that won't fit into Int/Long/Float/Double.

```
def permutations(n: Int): BigInt =
  (1 to n).map(BigInt(_)).foldLeft(BigInt(1))(_ * _)

def combinations(n: Int, k: Int): BigInt =
  permutations(n) / (permutations(k) * permutations(n - k))

combinations(1000, 35)
// res23: BigInt = 53007599712421378893801108296363791932591235151324218238066214600
```

Comment: This will be slow for larger n, say combinations(100000, 2).  A very much faster binomial coefficient implementation is at https://stackoverflow.com/a/65362753/29771.

Answer (score 0):

You don't really have to compute the large factorials.

If n >= k >= 1, then
C(n,k) = C(n-1, k-1) * n / k

How about this?

```scala
    def choose(n:Int,k:Int):BigInt = {
      if (k == 1)
        BigInt(n)
      else if (n == k)
        BigInt(1)
      else if (k == 0)
        BigInt(1)
      else
        choose(n-1, k-1) * n / k
    }
```